# iOS 16 TextEditor long text jumping (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swiftui, text, editor

Text jumping (I don't know how else to name that weird behavior) to the top(?) every time user enters a new character. I can reproduce the issue only on iPad OS 16. It affects the user who attempts to write long (several paragraphs) text in the TextEditor.

[image]

Reproduced with following code (just past five or more paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum and start typing)

```
class EditorViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
}

struct EditorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EditorViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $viewModel.text)
                .frame(height: 80)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        EditorView(
            viewModel: EditorViewModel()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I am seeing this behavior too on all devices. It started with iOS16. As you say, it only happens with long text. In my testing the first few edits of existing text might be fine, but if I scroll down in a document and start to type, the displayed text jumps all over the place even though the charters are inserted in the correct spot. This also happens in a UITextView.

Comment: Same problem here, on iOS 16.3.1 still not fixed. Maybe this edge case is not widely known?  This seems to be a huge bug in iOS.

Comment: I've written a [post on Apple Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724330), but there is no reaction to it.

Comment: Getting this on iOS 17, macOS 14. Just garbage.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ContentView`/parent view add

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = EditorViewModel()
```

Then change the body

```
EditorView(
    viewModel: viewModel
)
```

Per Apple

> Don’t specify a default or initial value for the observed object. Use the attribute only for a property that acts as an input for a view, as in the above example.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject

Comment: That's important but unrelated